# script to capture the package name from the commit message

Tags: powershell, gitlab-ci

I am trying to set up a GitLab ci pipeline to delete packages, the pipeline will trigger only after the merge request is approved, and the package name is captured from the $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE and pass it to the delete command to delete the package.

But the $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE which I have given during push (*decomm-xxx*) is been added with a few extra lines (*Merge branch `'ipl1`' into `'Condition`'
decomm-zzz
See Merge request lkjdscjnjsdcdsnjkjkj"*) after the MR is approved and merged.

How exactly can I capture the package name from the $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE which I originally gave (*decomm-xxx*), I need to print only the text after "*decomm-*" but I am not able to print it.

Any help on this would be much appreciated, thank you.

Below is the screenshot's which I tried.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Several ways to do it but, using what you're attempting to do, enclose the command with the array operator `@(..)`

Answer (score 0):

There's maybe a couple ways to do this:

1. Stop gitlab from adding the extra text
2. Write a script to accommodate the extra text added when merging an MR

## Change the commit message

To stop GitLab from adding the extra text, expand the dropdown under the merge button. This will let you edit the merge commit message:

[image: merge request UI]

## Write a more reliable script

Alternatively, you can write a script to reliably extract the text you need. Using regex is probably the most reasonable way to do this.

```yaml
script:
  - pattern='decomm-([A-z]+)'  # adjust this pattern to suit your needs
  - '[[ "$CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE" =~ $pattern ]]'
  - CIMessage="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
  - echo "$CIMessage" # zzz
```